# Multiply input value on keyup

Tags: jquery, input

How do I multiple the value of one input by 2 and save it to another input?

So when I type 10 (for example), the value of the 2nd input will be 20?

Thanks

Comment: You need to use the [jQuery basic arithmetic plugin](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)

Comment: @Pekka: This is hilarious! I love it!

Comment: @Pekka Nice :P, I'm saving that one

Comment: @elusive @ILMV yeah, I love it too! :) It's courtesy of our user bobince. http://www.doxdesk.com/

Comment: "I used the jQuery diet plugin and lost 10kg in a week." :D

Comment: HAHA! You should post that as an answer here so I can upvote it!

Comment: Somebody actually went and *implemented* that plugin. http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/buosj/add_a_number_to_another_number_in_javascript_img/c0on5ev

Comment: "Is there a jQuery plugin for making a HTML page appear in the browser". I cannot stop laughing :D

Comment: @Pekka: This is even better! "OMG you can add *and* subtract in the same chain!"

Comment: @elusive that indeed *is* a great feature!

Comment: -1 for using SO as a code writing service, and not even coming up with all the requirements beforehand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Two input fields**

```
<input type="text" id="input-value" />
<input type="text" id="output-value" readonly />
```

**And some simple jQuery**

```
var $output = $("#output-value");
$("#input-value").keyup(function() {
    var value = parseFloat($(this).val());
    $output.val(value*2);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming a structure like this:

```
<input id="inputfield1" type="text" />
<input id="inputfield2" type="text" />
```

you could use this code:

```
$("#inputfield1").keyup(function() { // when key is released in "#inputfield1"
// "change()" is also possible instead of "keyup()", slightly different behavior

    var input_value = parseFloat($("#inputfield1").val()); // get number as float
    // alternately parseInt(string, 10), in case you work with integers

    if (!isNaN(input_value)) { // the input is a number
        $("#inputfield2").val(input_value * 2); // update second field
    } else { // the input wasn't a number
        $("#inputfield2").val("not a number?"); // show an error mesage
    }
});
```

Comment: @user438755: Added the keyup event listener.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$('#input-2').val($('#input-1').val() * 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var orgNo = $('#textInput').val();
var newNo = org * 2;
$('#textOutput').val(newNo);
```

Comment: I think you meant `* 2` there, not `* 10`; also, `new` is a reserved word.