# Multiply value on input [type='number'] by 250

Tags: jquery, input, multiplication

I need to have an `input [type='number']`  multiplying its quantity by the value of 250.
I want a situation similar of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707271/multiply-input-value-on-keyup)... i tried to use the code on this link but since i am using `input [type='number']`, the values simply didn´t update!

Does anyone know how to have this working with this kind of `input` with `Jquery`?

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: can you paste your code here?

Comment: Show us what you have right now

Comment: Remember that you need to put the answer from the linked question into a closure, like: `$(document).ready(function() { [logic] });`.

Comment: What do you mean by 'different input type' ? Unless you tell us that it's difficult to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/g9fUf/

if you having problem with `readonly` than you can use `disabled`

```
<input type="text" id="output-value" disabled/>
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="number" id="input-value" />
<input type="text" id="output-value" readonly />
```

**js**

```
var $output = $("#output-value");
$("#input-value").keyup(function() {
    var value = parseFloat($(this).val());
    $output.val(value*250);
});
```

Comment: I want exactly something like this. I´ve checked the demo but the readonly field it´s not updating the value!!!!

Comment: check i have made a change

Comment: You cannot use `disabled` instead of `readonly`. `readonly` is send with the request, while `disabled` is not. That's not equivalent attributes!

Comment: he just need to calculate the values and he is not using readonly because he need to change the value by script not by client.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `change` event for this :

```
$("input").on("change keyup", function () {
    var value = parseInt(this.value, 10);
    this.value = value * 250;
});
```

Assuming `input` is a tag like this :

```
<input type="number" />
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/VzysM/1/

**Note** : I added `keyup` just in case someone types the number rather than using the rangepicker.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code on the focusout of the input type get the value and multiply.And then set that value .

```
$("#id").focusout(function(){
    var value = $("#id").val() *250;
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lo t for your comment. I need the value updated in another input not in the same input.! :)

Comment: so set this value in that input type id

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<input id="field1" type="number" />
<input id="field2" type="number" />
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#field1").keyup(function() { 
    var input_value = parseFloat($("#field1").val());     
    $("#field2").val(input_value * 250);   
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a normal text input you can use this:

```
$("#input1").keyup(function(){
 var input1 = parseInt($("#input1").val());
 if(!isNaN(input1)){
     $("#input2").val(input1 * 250);
 }
 else{
     $("#input2").val("");
     alert("Please enter a valid number");
 }
});
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/aL6cP/2/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for all of you who helped me!!! I found a solution... I´ve merged the solutions of hungerpain and Tushar Gupta and it´s working as i want!!!!! :)

I wanted to share a fiddle with the solution but no sucess with that... Stackoverflow for me it´s giving me a bug!!!

So the final code was:

```
var $output = $("#output-value");
$("#input-value").on("change keyup", function () {
    var value = parseFloat($(this).val());
    $output.val(value*250);
});

<input type="number" id="input-value" />
<input type="text" id="output-value" readonly />
```